# Raspistill in manual exposure

Tags: camera, raspicam

I found that using raspistill or Camera py module I cannot set lower speeds than 1/30" (converted to nano secs).
I want manual camera settings ISO = value and ss = value
All is fine in daylights but when lower speeds are needed I cannot set them slower than 1/30", they are automatically set to 1/30" or so.
If I only set an ISO value, shutter speed is auto set to lower values like 1/15" or less.
Is this a bug or there's something I am missing?
Thank you

Comment: If I understand correctly you're wanting longer exposure times (i.e. that's what you mean by slower speeds)? If that's the case you need to drop the framerate of the camera ([exposure time is limited by framerate](http://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.13/fov.html#maximum-exposure-time-is-determined-by-the-minimum-framerate) - worth reading the rest of that chapter too for lots of info on how the camera operates)

Comment: That's right, longer exposures.  So despite I am not filming I must to reduce framerate, for example "-fps 2" to set fps to its minimum (as I read in user manual) 2 fps.   
2 frames per seconds means I cannot set exposures longer the 1/2 sec or 500000 nano secs. Is that so?
I've read that 6 seconds (6000000 nano secs) is the longest exposure time possible , only in auto ISO & speed?

Comment: The 2 fps I give in that chapter is for a hypothetical example (that whole first section is hypothetical but gives an overview of how rolling shutter cameras work). The Pi's v1 camera module can do 1/6th fps and thus 6 sec exposures, while the v2 camera module can do 1/10th fps and thus 10 sec exposures. The table later on in the chapter gives the limits of the various modes.

Comment: I'm still stuck. -fps --framerate is an option for raspivid but I am not filmming, I'm using raspistill (photos - slow speed - long exposures)

Comment: Ah, if I recall correctly (been a while since I looked at the code) raspistill sets an "auto" framerate on the camera (it's a little more complex than that but anyway) so there's no need to specify it with raspistill (just the python module). However, you will need to increase the capture timeout significantly due to the requirement to gather frames for AGC and AWB, so try something like "raspistill -ss 6000000 -t 30000 -o long_exposure.jpg" for a 6 second exposure.

Comment: But that is the main issue of my question.  With raspistill despite I set long exposures they are automatically set to 1/30", so, underexposed images. I read metadata with exiftool

Comment: With the command I gave above I get a JPEG with 6s listed under "shutter speed" and "exposure time" when queried with exiftool (and the image looks quite bright despite capturing in the dark). Which attributes are you looking at?

Comment: Im not in my computer but I was able to run your command remotely and as you stated exposure was long.  I have a lot of more options in my command, perhaps one is originating the problem. awb is off, I set blue and red custom values. When Im back I’ll add the complete command into the main question (should have add it before)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68182/discussion-between-dstonek-and-dave-jones).