# PiCamera long exposures

Tags: camera, raspicam

Revisiting this issue [Raspistill in manual exposure](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/74648/raspistill-in-manual-exposure)
I found that the shutter time of the photo I got from this command

```
raspistill -ss 6000000 -t 30000 -o long_exposure.jpg
```

is 6 seconds as expected but when I run this script

```
from picamera import PiCamera    
from time import sleep    
from datetime import datetime      
camera = PiCamera()    
camera.start_preview()    
camera.resolution = (3280,2464)     
camera.awb_mode = 'off'    
red, blue = (1.5, 1.45) # 5500K    
camera.iso = 100    
camera.shutter_speed = 6000000  # 6 secs     
datedate = datetime.now().strftime("%a-%d.%m.%Y-%H:%M:%S")     
nombre = '/home/pi/Pictures/IMG-' + datedate + '.jpg'     
sleep(2)    
camera.capture(nombre)    
camera.stop_preview()
```

shutter time is 1/30 secs = 33333 nano secs

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you're still having this issue, but it worked for me when I also set the camera.framerate equal to 1/exposure time, I think you have to do both or it will default to the default framerate of 30fps.

Comment: I marked this answer as correct because I can shoot manual slow speed despite I see some discrepancies like setting framerate=0.5 shutter speed=2000000 and the exif metadata outputs speed=1sec